# Spring, webflux: The getRemoteAddress method of the ServerHttpRequest object returns null when request performed from WebTestClient

Tags: spring, spring-test, spring-webflux

I have a controller

```
@RestController
public class NameController {

    @Autowired
    private NameService nameService;

    @GetMapping("/name")
    public Mono<UploadParamsDto> getName(ServerHttpRequest request) {
            return nameService.getNameByHost(request.getRemoteAddress().getHostName());
    }
}
```

and i have a test method:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(NameControllerTest.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class NameControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webClient;

    @Test
    void nameTest() {
        webClient.get().uri("/name")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk();
    }
}
```

When I run the test in order to check my getName method i got NPE because
request.getRemoteAddress() returns null, could you please tell me how to mock ServerHttpRequest? (I know that there is MockServerHttpRequest, but I couldn't managed with it)

My purpose is make request.getRemoteAddress().getHostName() return mock value.

Comment: Good explanation [example](https://techotom.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/mocking-remoteaddr-with-spring-mvc/)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to everyone.
Works in next way:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(NameControllerTest.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class NameControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    void nameTest() {

        WebTestClient webClient = WebTestClient
                    .bindToApplicationContext(context)
                    .webFilter(new SetRemoteAddressWebFilter("127.0.0.1"))
                    .configureClient()
                    .build();

        webClient.get().uri("/name")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk();
    }
}
```

Where SetRemoteAddressWebFilter is WebFilter:

```
public class SetRemoteAddressWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    private String host;

    public SetRemoteAddressWebFilter(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.filter(decorate(exchange));
    }

    private ServerWebExchange decorate(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        final ServerHttpRequest decorated = new ServerHttpRequestDecorator(exchange.getRequest()) {
            @Override
            public InetSocketAddress getRemoteAddress() {
                return new InetSocketAddress(host, 80);
            }
        };

        return new ServerWebExchangeDecorator(exchange) {
            @Override
            public ServerHttpRequest getRequest() {
                return decorated;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running a test with `@WebFluxTest` doesn't involve a real server, you've figured that out.

But getting a `NullPointerException` doesn't feel right still - could you create an issue on https://jira.spring.io about that? I don't think you should have to work around this, but Spring Framework should probably provide  some infrastructure to "mock" that information.

Comment: Was this addressed?